# How can I include a ScrollView inside a Touchable component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, touchableopacity

I have a main `View` component containing a `ScrollView` image carousel and another `View` that includes some `Text` component. I want to touch over the main `View` and open another app view, but I need to scroll images too.

I tried to put the main `View` inside a `TouchableOpacity` (I tried `TouchableHighlight` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback` too) and it doesn't work fine.

The following code is how I am trying to solve it:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showView}>
  <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <Image
          key={index}
          source={image}
        />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.title}>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        <Text>{sample text}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) applied to this main `View` might work for you instead wrapping the View inside any `Touchable{...}` Component.